# How to insert a single cuneiform (Sumerian) unicode character in a XeTeX document?

Tags: unicode

I have seen examples of inserting single characters when the font package is known, as in the following example with the character "anchor" using dingbat. But I do not know how to do it with a cuneiform character, which in Unicode is U+121A0 (for the Sumerian word *ki*). In the following example, the anchor prints but the *ki* character doesn't. I know I have to type the corresponding package but I don't know the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\newunicodechar{}{\ki}
\newunicodechar{⚓}{\anchor}

\begin{document}

\ki
\anchor

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question my browser picked the font Segoe UI Historic to show that character, so I used the same with lualatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\foo{Segoe UI Historic}

\begin{document}

Blah blah {\foo }  {\huge\foo } blah.

\end{document}
```

---

firefox inspect menu:

[image]

---

You can also use the freely available google font `Noto Sans Cuneiform Regular`

Comment: Thanks! I tried running your example, but I got an error message: The font "SegoeUHistoric" can not be found. I think I have the same problem as before, i.e., how to install packages for Unicode.

Comment: @FZaldivar you do not need packages you just need a font.  That is a standard windows font but if you can see the character in your question you must have some font, so you could do the same and use whichever font your browser is using. or use  the command `albatross U+121A0` to list the fonts on your system that have that character

Comment: @FZaldivar what operating system and what web browser do you use?

Comment: I am using MacOS and Firefox

Comment: ok in firefox right click on the character and select inspect then look at the fonts tab in the lower right (see my image) what fonts does it show?

Comment: Firefox inspect:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

 [1]:  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sv2qny1oa469prrnacpjn/Screenshot-2023-11-10-at-3.55.07-PM.png?rlkey=wr2to4qo253jsffe7l6h1w0m1&dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149637/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-f-zaldivar).

Comment: I succeeded: after installing the new TexLive (2023) version, essentially using your code, with Emacs with Skim running lualatex I got the result. My only question is now: Is it possible to call the Unicode character U+121A0 by calling it with this code number instead of typing and saving the Sumerian symbol    as in your code?

Comment: In addition, TexShop can not run the code, but that does not worry me, since I can use Emacs. The question about typing a code, for example, using: \text{\symbol{121A0}} is that my whole document would be in ASCII when I submitted it to the journal.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that in StackExchange the web rendering changes the Sumerian symbol in a random manner.

Comment: you can use \symbol but need `"` prefix for hex so `\symbol{"121A0}`  nothing is ever random, so I can not guess what you mean by the last comment. also Emacs, texshop are not involved, they are just the editors of the source file @FZaldivar

Comment: @FZaldivar check with the journal but they may not accept using  a font you may have to use an image